# How to use GIT in this specific situation

Tags: git

I am currently developing sort of a hardware abstraction layer for a microcontroller. The build process is Makefile driven and the manufacturer supplies a SDK. I would now like to build my board/application on top of this SDK. The SDK structure looks like this:

```
boards
├─ manufacturer_board1
│  ├─ bsp
│  ├─ examples
├─ my_board_x
│  ├─ bsp
│  ├─ application1
│  ├─ application2
bootloader
CMSIS
devices
docs
```

Apparently the example projects and Makefiles for those projects are stored in the manufacturer_board1/examples folder

I could now easily fork the SDK and put my files into a completely different GIT repository with the added cost that I must heavily modify the Makefiles, maybe event to the point that I have to specify absolute paths which I want to avoid completely.

The more elegant solution to me looks like I could add my code on top of the SDK repository (basically the whole my_board_x directory structure). This way, I can reuse all the Makefiles and can stick to the SDK as close as possible.

If the SDK gets updated, I make an update to the SDK repo; if my project gets updated, I make an update to the my_board_x directory.

So, what's the main question here: Can this be done with GIT? Is it a good idea? Would you recommend another approach?

I know that there probably is no 100% correct answer but I would like to get an idea if what I'm trying to do makes any sense at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your scenario correctly, you have a classic scenario with your own fork and an upstream repository, from which you will periodically pull updates. If so, you should create a fork of the manufacturer SDK and then configure the original SDK repository as the upstream repository, as described in [Configuring a remote repository for a fork](https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/collaborating-with-pull-requests/working-with-forks/configuring-a-remote-repository-for-a-fork).

Comment: There's one thing I have not mentioned yet. The manufacturer distributes those files as a ZIP package, not a real repository. Yet, I guess for this approach it shouldn't matter because I want to throw these into a distinct repository. So if I understand you correctly I could easily create the "manufacturer" repo, then create a fork from that, put my changes into the (local) fork and configure the manufacturer repository to be a upstream repo for my fork. If the manufacturer distributes a new ZIP I would put those into the manufacturer repo and from my fork pull the changes into my fork?

Comment: Yes, @TomL., that sounds like a clean solution.
However, if that's just a ZIP and you have permission to the "manufacturer repo", then an easier solution would be to simply manage these two "repos" in two separate branches of a single repo: start with one branch for the "manufacturer" and create another one from it for your dev work. Then you'll be able to update the "manufacturer" branch when it is checked out with new manufacturer updates, and then merge changes from it to your dev branch.
Just make sure you only develop on the dev branch, and the other branch contains only SDK updates.